# Flot bar chart with AngularJS: bars not lining up with ticks

Tags: jquery, angularjs, flot

I'm using AngularJS and Flot to plot a bar chart:

See jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/juliejones/DwMwJ/3/

The directive:

```
App.directive('barChart', function(){
return{
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){

        var weekday=new Array();
        weekday[0]="Su";
        weekday[1]="Mo";
        weekday[2]="Tu";
        weekday[3]="We";
        weekday[4]="Th";
        weekday[5]="Fr";
        weekday[6]="Sa";

        var options = {
            bars: {
                show: true,
                barWidth: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 0.7,
                align: 'center'
            },
            colors: ["#F90"],
            xaxis: {
                mode: 'time',
                tickSize: [1, 'day'],
                minTickSize: [1, 'day'],
                tickFormatter: function (val, axis) {
                    var d = new Date(val);
                    return weekday[d.getUTCDay()] + '<br />' + d.getUTCDate();
                }
            },
            yaxis: {
                minTickSize: 1,
                tickDecimals: 0,
                min: 0
            }
        };
        var chart = null;

        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(v){
            if(!chart){
                chart = $.plot(elem, v , options);
                elem.show();
            }else{
                chart.setData(v);
                chart.setupGrid();
                chart.draw();
            }
        });
    }
};
});
```

The data (identical except for the value of the first item):

```
var data1 = [[
    [1364774400000, ], 
    [1365206400000, 5], 
    [1365292800000, 2],
    [1365379200000, 2]
   ]];

var data2 = [[
    [1364774400000, 0], 
    [1365206400000, 5], 
    [1365292800000, 2],
    [1365379200000, 2]
   ]];
```

The chart looks great as long as the first data point has a null value. The 3 bars are centered perfectly on their ticks. See the jsFiddle.

Click the 'Change data' button to load the second set of data which has a zero value in the first data point. The three bars move so they are no longer centered and are now nowhere near where they should be on the x axis.

Why are the bars not centered over the correct ticks when using the second set of data? And how can I correct this?

Edit: This works perfectly for me when AngularJS is not involved. See jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/juliejones/fC3zs/1/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the alignTicksWithAxis: 1, directive in the xaxis. This will align your values with your bars.

Here is a working fiddle: `http://jsfiddle.net/u8csX/`

Added some more data points to second data set just to verify that it indeed aligns. If you want more space for labels then you can modify the labelWidth / labelHeight property. I've done that too in the fiddle which makes your yaxis more visible.

Also the API is very helpful: `http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt`

Comment: Thanks for your reply but isn't alignTicksWithAxis only useful when you have 2 y-axes? One to the left and one to the right? It doesn't seem to help my situation anyway. The second set of data still isn't centered on the tick. In the first set of data the bar with a value of 5 is centered on 'Sa 6'. In the second set of data that bar is located to the right of 'Fr 5'.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my own question...

In the directive I changed:

```
return weekday[d.getUTCDay()] + '<br />' + d.getUTCDate();
```

to:

```
return weekday[d.getDay()] + '<br />' + d.getDate();
```

and (under 'bars') removed:

```
align: 'center'
```

Now when changing from one data set to another, the x axis label stay in place.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be related to this:
[flot chart in angular.js directive has zero dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291656/flot-chart-in-angular-js-directive-has-zero-dimensions)

Using the 'E' on directive gives wrong size information to flot, use 'A' instead.